# Grab data from Yahoo Finance using Meteor Package, some work some do not

Tags: json, meteor, yahoo-finance

I am using the following package for Meteor https://atmospherejs.com/ajbarry/yahoo-finance

I cant seem to get a specified field to work, [here](https://github.com/pilwon/node-yahoo-finance/blob/master/lib/fields.js) is a link that contains a list of all the available fields, however 'j2' and some others I tested don't work, in the sense there is no response in the result object, or no json key pair values.

Heres is my client side code.

```
Template.stock.rendered = function (){
    if ( _.isEmpty(Session.get('ENW.V')) ) {
        Meteor.call('getQuote', 'ENW.V', function(err, result) {
            Session.set('ENW.V', result['ENW.V']);
            console.log(result)
        });
    }
}


Template.stock.helpers({
    stock: function() {
        return Session.get('ENW.V');
    }
})
```

Server side Method

```
Meteor.methods({
  getQuote: function( stockname ) {
    return YahooFinance.snapshot({symbols: [stockname] , fields:['n','a','b','j2'] });
  }
});
```

Thanks for any Help in Advance. Happy to add any additional info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a test run after commenting out that line and it seems to work fine. Create an issue with the package owner to see if you can have it fixed for the long run.

---

The package you are using is deliberately excluding those fields. For what reason, I cannot say. For a full list of fields that it is avoiding, look here:

https://github.com/pilwon/node-yahoo-finance/blob/master/lib/index.js#L122