# Dummy financial API data

Tags: meteor, financial

I'm building a financial valuation web and mobile application in Meteor. For now, the app includes the ability for users to populate company fundamentals (revenue, net income, etc) and closing stock prices themselves. This will not be an attractive long-term solution for adoption, given the availability of market data, so I will eventually need to hook into a financial API, likely Xignite. Since I am very far from launch and not looking to pay for this data just yet (free trials are short), I am looking for a way to add dummy code that I can easily strip out when it comes time to plug in the real thing.

Do any providers offer something like this for development? I would imagine not, since why would they provide it without the guarantee I'm going to pay them someday? Perhaps a package somewhere? For now, I am including dummy data through fixtures in my "companies" collection, but this feels like a poor stopgap measure and doesn't let me address historical prices. I know that when the time comes, I'll have a lot of work ahead of me to hook in the real API and I'm brand new at this (first thing I've ever built). Better to do it right the first time than scrapping work later on.

Thank you.
Brendan

Comment: You picked the most cut-throat, least open-source industry possible for your first project :-) Try Yahoo Finance API (make .csv & import). Also look to the Excel add-in called SMF, it'll show you what's possible just by scraping pages.

Comment: Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063992/grab-data-from-yahoo-finance-using-meteor-package-some-work-some-do-not/30066450#30066450

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see I would image two solutions:

1. The service ur looking for (and probably is payed like you said) might have an api for development purposes with fake test data. They maybe are willing to give you access to this development api if you are telling you are willing to use their service in the future.
2. Another option is to use a faker library like [FakerJS](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) which works in the client/server (nodejs on the server) or the [meteor-fake](https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-fake/) package

Hope this helps you further

Comment: Thank you, hoping option 1 is possible, looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

[Intrinio](http://intrin.io/intrinio_sof), where I work, provides 500/daily API calls to it's fundamentals data feed which includes historical stock prices and financial statement data. It's not a trial, it's just free. There are several other data types with free plans.

Here is an example in curl:

```
curl "https://api.intrinio.com/prices?ticker=AAPL" -u "fd7d79d98502e273129a08229d1261a0:c18a828da565a9047896067233550ab8"
```

You can [see a tutorial here](http://intrin.io/web_api_tutorial_sof).

The point is to let you test out, and build, without commitment or paying. Of course Intrinio hopes you will end up paying, but the idea is to make it possible to build an app without wasting dev time using "fake" data.